# MVC SpringBoot application with MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am learning SpringBoot connected with MongoDb and I am trying to prepare small project however I do not get why I still have an exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:Error creating bean with name 'movieController' defined in file [C:\MoviesManager\target\classes\com\manager\MovieController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'movieRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type Movie!

It looks like something went wrong with my MovieController or MovieRepository class. There are all annotation I should use however I can not launch application. Could you please help me?

Here you are my classes:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieController {
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

public MovieController(MovieRepository movieRepository){
    this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
}//some CRUD methods

@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends MongoRepository<Movie, String>{
    public Movie findOneByName(String name);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a query method findOneByName, but apparently your Movie class doesn't have a property called `name` (the class must define at least a get method for that).

If you have a `name` property, but it is your ID (annotated with `@Id`), I believe you also can't define custom query methods like that, but you can use the predefined `findById()` instead (or `findOne` in Spring Data 1.x).

If this doesn't solve your problem, please show the Movie class.